# how to behave all data as a single group in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset and I need to groupby my dataset based on column `group`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


arr = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46])
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                   "target": arr})

for g_name, g_df in df.groupby("group"):
    print("GROUP: {}".format(g_name))
    print(g_df)
```

However, sometimes `group` might not exist as a column and in this case, I am trying to whole data as a single group.

```
for g_name, g_df in df.groupby(SOMEPARAMETERS):
    print(g_df)

output:
target
  1
  2
  4
  7
  11
  16
  22
  29
  37
  46
```

Is it possible to change the parameter of `groupby` to get whole data as a single group?

Comment: What do you mean with whole data as a single group? Can you give an example?

Comment: you can use for example `df.groupby([1]*len(df))` , but what is the use case really?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean something like this where you have two columns on which you want to group:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


arr = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46])

df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                   'group2': ['C', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'C'],
                   'target': arr})
```

Then you can easily extend your example with:

```
for g_name, g_df in df.groupby(["group1", "group2"]):
    print("GROUP: {}".format(g_name))
    print(g_df)
```

Is this what you meant?